# Is it possible to modify solar panels to work off of nuclear radiation instead of solar radiation?

Tags: energy

On my understanding of how solar panels work, solar rays enters the cell, and a chemical reaction turns that into power. Nuclear radiation is a flow of extra electrons i beleive, and solar rays are similar. So shouldent it be possible to use nuclear radiation to a modified system similar to that of a solar panel? And does this tech already exist? If it does, what is it called? If it is not possible, why? How would it be done if it is possible?

-edit- 
I mean getting energy from places where nuclear disasters have happened, like a nuclear power plant melting down. Because of the resulting radiation, we cannot inhabit that place. so creating a device that could harness that radiation to make electricity would be great, because you could make some use of radiation that already is bouncing around.

Comment: Nuclear radiation encompasses a variety of things like gamma, beta, and alpha radiation. Solar power works of electromagnetic waves due to sunlight through the photoelectric effect.

Comment: Not exactly the tech that you are asking about, but you may be interested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioisotope_thermoelectric_generator

Comment: @Triatticus I'm not quite sure what you mean by this. Do you mean it is not possible?

Comment: I'm just saying that nuclear radiation is a broad term, and isn't just "free flowing electrons.". Certainly if someone could make a photovoltaic cell for the range of gamma radiation off a nuclear emission it would certainly work.

Answer (score 3):

Such devices have existed for some time in the following form: the radiation emitted by a chosen type of nuclear decay strikes a chemical which glows in response. Next to that chemical is a photocell which converts the glow into a (feeble but still useful) flow of electricity. This is called an [optoelectric nuclear battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optoelectric_nuclear_battery).

Another approach is to simply use the heat generated in the decay to generate electricity using a thermocouple, the resulting glorified nuclear kettle being called a [radioisotope thermoelectric generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioisotope_thermoelectric_generator).

Power sources like this are used in deep space probes that travel too far from the sun to produce enough electricity using conventional solar panels to run their instruments and radios (an RTG powers the *Voyager 2*, and a mention of one *The Martian* is scientifically accurate). The decay can continue for decades and there are no moving parts to be broken, so they are good for long missions, but you’d be crazy to use them around people.